# How to have 4 sizable images HTML Wordpress

Tags: html, wordpress, web

On Apple.com, their homepage, underneath the slides, you see 4 clickable posts/images and when you scale the browser window(or use a phone or tablet), they scale according.

Is their a plugin for Wordpress that mimics this type of behavior or HTML code?

Where you can have 4 images to scale to the UI, simple HTML code?

I know there are plugins that do this with latest posts but its not what I want. Thank you in advance.

[Example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h2uOy.png)

Answer (score 0):

They are using the background-size attribute. What that does is ensure the image is contained within the parent element and scaled up or down to ensure that it's at 100% width and height but still within the parent container.

It accepts a couple of properties. Here is the table of [browser support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=background-img-opts).

```
background-size: contain;
```

Contains the image within the parent element and does not overflow.

```
background-size: cover;
```

Ensures the background image covers the full width and height of the element it is applied to. It won't skew the aspect ratio, it will simply overflow the element to the right size to maintain the aspect ratio.

Also, just to note, you can use pixels and media queries to explicitly set the image width/height ratio. This would look like this and goes in the order of *width then height* and if you use one value instead of two, that will also work.

```
background-size: 250px 150px;
```

Note that the background image is contained to the element it is applied to regardless. So even though it **technically overflows** when using cover, ***it doesn't visually spill over the element*** so it doesn't look messy.